# LINQ parameter 'x' is not in scope

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

Following my question regarding the formulation of an [IQueryable to query a recursive database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429855/), I tried the answer that was given and got a lot closer to the solution for my problem. I've restructured the provided answer so for me it easier to understand what is going on. However, whatever I try I keep on getting the error message `"the parameter 'x' is not in scope"` on the line `return entities.Single();`. How can I make sure that the paramenter 'x' is IN scope? I've tried making the `ParameterExpression` in the `BuildParentPropertiesExpression` method, I've tried putting it in the for-loop with a different name every time. All to no avail.

[Read background story here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429855/)

```
public Entity Single(string path)
{
    if (path[0] == '/')
        path = path.Substring(1); // only absolute paths for now

    List<string> pathParts = path.Split('/').ToList();
    pathParts.Reverse();

    var entities =
        from entity in dataContext.Entities
        select entity;

    // Build up a template expression that will be used to create the real expressions with.
    Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> templateExpression = (x => x.Code == "dummy");
    BinaryExpression equals = (BinaryExpression)templateExpression.Body;
    MemberExpression property = (MemberExpression)equals.Left;

    ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity), "x");

    for (int index = 0; index < pathParts.Count; index++)
    {
        string pathPart = pathParts[index];

        Expression parentPropertyExpression = BuildParentPropertiesExpression(index, entityParameter);

        MemberExpression left = Expression.Property(
            parentPropertyExpression,
            (PropertyInfo)property.Member
        );

        ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant(pathPart);

        BinaryExpression equalExpression = Expression.Equal(
            left, 
            right, 
            equals.IsLiftedToNull, 
            equals.Method
        );

        var entityFilterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(
            equalExpression, 
            templateExpression.Parameters
        );

        entities = entities.Where<Entity>(entityFilterExpression);
    }

    return entities.Single();
}

private Expression BuildParentPropertiesExpression(int numberOfParents, ParameterExpression entityParameter)
{
    if (numberOfParents == 0)
        return entityParameter;

    var getParentMethod = typeof(Entity).GetProperty("Entity1").GetGetMethod();
    var property = Expression.Property(entityParameter, getParentMethod);

    for (int count = 2; count <= numberOfParents; count++)
        property = Expression.Property(property, getParentMethod);

    return property;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it might be because your query is selecting `entity` and not `x`

Comment: @DigitalD Interesting suggestion however renaming `x` to `entity` gives me the message "the parameter 'entity' is not in scope". I think the name of the parameter does not make a difference. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: All of them: `(x => x.Code == "dummy")` to `(entity => entity.Code == "dummy")` and `Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity), "x")` to `Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity), "entity")`

Comment: I think I misunderstood the article you referenced. The code he shared is not a complete solution since it's just part of a decompiled solution from the expanded query he built.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close with your original implementation

```
public Entity Single(string path) {
    string[] pathParts = path.Split('/');
    string code = pathParts[pathParts.Length -1];

    if (pathParts.Length == 1)
            return dataContext.Entities.Single(e => e.Code == code && e.ParentID == 0);

    IQueryable<Entity> entities = dataContext.Entities.Where(e => e.Code == code);
    for (int i = pathParts.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        string parentCode = pathParts[i];
        entities = entities.Where(e => e.Entity1.Code == parentCode).Select(e => e.Entity1); //This now gets the parent entity
    }

    return entities.Single();
}
```

Comment: I've always been under the impression that `Select()` makes a call to the database, therefore you would have just made more than one call the database. With `IQueryable` and `Where()` the call to the database is deferred until the moment you use the variable `entities`, in this case at the `return entities.Single()`. Can you provide me with an article or a proof of concept showing me that `Select()` is also deferred, and I don't end up with a potentially  enormous number of database calls?

Comment: Also, it doesn't return the correct Entity now. It returns the parent Entity instead of the one that has the parent Entity matching the pathPart. For example: "foo/baz/bar" should return the entity with Code == "bar", with your solution it return the entity with Code == "foo"

Comment: Sorry then. I'm honestly not sure how to build that.